# what is the sql query to search a containing word using like

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c

I am using sql query using like but it is not returning any thing in below code

```
NSString *strSelectQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM tblrestaurant WHERE address LIKE '%@'",txtField.text];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE Name like '%%%Searchterm%%'

Answer (score 4):

You need `%` characters around the search text. Try this:

```
NSString *strSelectQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM tblrestaurant WHERE address LIKE '%%%@%%'",txtField.text];
```

Note that the `%` symbols are escaped. So yes, that is three `%`, then the `@`, and then two more `%`.